# In antlr4.7 how to parse a rule like ISO 8601 interval "P3M2D" ahead of an "ID" rule

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am trying to parse [ISO 8601 period expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) like "P3M2D", using `antlr4`. But I am hitting some kind of roadblock and will appreciate help. I am rather new to both antlr and compilers.

My grammar is as below. I have combined the lexer and parser rules in one go here:

```
grammar test_iso ;
// import testLexerRules ;

iso : ( date_expr NEWLINE)* EOF;

date_expr
    :   date_expr op=( '+' | '-' ) iso8601_interval #dateexpr_Interval
    |   date_expr op='-' date_expr                  #dateexpr_Diff
    |   DATETIME_NAME                               #dateexpr_Named
    |   '(' inner=date_expr ')'                     #dateexpr_Paren
    ;

///////////////////////////////////////////

iso8601_interval
    :   iso8601_interval_d
        { System.out.println("ISO8601_INTERVAL DATE seen " + $text);}
    ;

iso8601_interval_d
    :   'P' ( y=NUMBER_INT 'Y' )? ( m=NUMBER_INT 'M' )? ( w=NUMBER_INT 'W' )? ( d=NUMBER_INT 'D' )?
    ;

///////////////////////////////////////////
// in separate file : test_lexer.g4
// lexer grammar testLexerRules ;
///////////////////////////////////////////

fragment
TODAY 
    :   'today' | 'TODAY' 
    ;
fragment
NOW 
    :   'now' | 'NOW' 
    ;

DATETIME_NAME
    :   TODAY
    |   NOW
    ;

///////////////////////////////////////////

NUMBER_INT
    :   '-'? INT                    // -3, 45
    ;

fragment
DIGIT :     [0-9] ;

fragment
INT :       '0' | [1-9] DIGIT* ;

//////////////////////////////////////////////

//
// identifiers
//

ID 
    :   ALPHA ALPH_NUM* 
    { System.out.println("ID seen " + getText()); }
    ;

ID_SQLFUNC
    :   'h$' ALPHA_UPPER ALPHA_UPPER_NUM*
    { System.out.println("SQL FUNC seen " + getText()); }
    ;

fragment
ALPHA :    [a-zA-Z] ;

fragment
ALPH_NUM : [a-zA-Z_0-9] ;

fragment
ALPHA_UPPER :    [A-Z] ;

fragment
ALPHA_UPPER_NUM : [A-Z_0-9] ;

//////////////////////////////////////////////

NEWLINE : '\r\n' ;
WS  :  [ \t]+ -> skip  ;
```

In test run, it never hits the `iso8601_interval_d` rule, it always goes to `ID` rule.

```
C:\lab>java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig test_iso iso -tokens -tree
now + P3M2D
^Z
ID seen P3M2D
[@0,0:2='now',<DATETIME_NAME>,1:0]
[@1,4:4='+',<'+'>,1:4]
[@2,6:10='P3M2D',<ID>,1:6]
[@3,11:12='\r\n',<'
'>,1:11]
[@4,13:12='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
line 1:6 mismatched input 'P3M2D' expecting 'P'
ISO8601_INTERVAL DATE seen P3M2D
(iso (date_expr (date_expr now) + (iso8601_interval (iso8601_interval_d P3M2D))) \r\n <EOF>)
```

If I remove the "ID" rule and run again, it parses as desired:

```
now + P3M2D
^Z
[@0,0:2='now',<DATETIME_NAME>,1:0]
[@1,4:4='+',<'+'>,1:4]
[@2,6:6='P',<'P'>,1:6]
[@3,7:7='3',<NUMBER_INT>,1:7]
[@4,8:8='M',<'M'>,1:8]
[@5,9:9='2',<NUMBER_INT>,1:9]
[@6,10:10='D',<'D'>,1:10]
[@7,11:12='\r\n',<'
'>,1:11]
[@8,13:12='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
ISO8601_INTERVAL DATE seen P3M2D
(iso (date_expr (date_expr now) + (iso8601_interval (iso8601_interval_d P 3 M 2 D))) \r\n <EOF>)
```

I also tried prefixing a special character like "@" in the parser rule

```
iso8601_interval_d
    :   '@P' ( y=NUMBER_INT 'Y' )? ( m=NUMBER_INT 'M' )? ( w=NUMBER_INT 'W' )? ( d=NUMBER_INT 'D' )?
    ;
```

but now a different kind of failure

```
now + @P3M2D
^Z
ID seen M2D
[@0,0:2='now',<DATETIME_NAME>,1:0]
[@1,4:4='+',<'+'>,1:4]
[@2,6:7='@P',<'@P'>,1:6]
[@3,8:8='3',<NUMBER_INT>,1:8]
[@4,9:11='M2D',<ID>,1:9]
[@5,12:13='\r\n',<'
'>,1:12]
[@6,14:13='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
line 1:9 no viable alternative at input '3M2D'
ISO8601_INTERVAL DATE seen @P3M2D
(iso (date_expr (date_expr now) + (iso8601_interval (iso8601_interval_d @P 3 M2D))) \r\n <EOF>)
```

I am sure I am not the first one to hit upon something like this. What is the antlr idiom here?

EDIT -- I need the `ID` token elsewhere in other parts of my grammar that I have omitted here, to highlight the problem I am facing.

Comment: why do you need the ID token ?

Comment: I abstracted a fragment of my grammar to highlight my problem. I need ID token elsewhere in other rules that I have omitted.

Comment: whoever downvoted, can you please leave a comment why downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like find out even by other, the issue is in the ID token. The fact is that the duration syntax for iso-8601 is a valid ID. Besides the solution figured out by @Mike. If something called [island grammar](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687313/Island+Grammars+Under+Parser+Control) is suitable for your needs you can use ANTLR's  [lexical modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md) to *exclude* the ID lexer rule while parsing an iso date.
Belove there is an examples on how it could work

```
parser grammar iso;
options { tokenVocab=iso_lexer; }

iso : ISO_BEGIN ( date_expr NEWLINE)* ISO_END;

date_expr
    :   date_expr op=( '+' | '-' ) iso8601_interval #dateexpr_Interval
    |   date_expr op='-' date_expr                  #dateexpr_Diff
    |   DATETIME_NAME                               #dateexpr_Named
    |   '(' inner=date_expr ')'                     #dateexpr_Paren
    ;

///////////////////////////////////////////

iso8601_interval
    :   iso8601_interval_d
        { System.out.println("ISO8601_INTERVAL DATE seen " + $text);}
    ;

iso8601_interval_d
    :   'P' ( y=NUMBER_INT 'Y' )? ( m=NUMBER_INT 'M' )? ( w=NUMBER_INT 'W' )? ( d=NUMBER_INT 'D' )?
    ;
```

then in the lexer

```
lexer grammar iso_lexer;

//
// identifiers (in DEFAULT_MODE)
//

ISO_BEGIN
    : '<@' -> mode(ISO)
    ;

ID
    :   ALPHA ALPH_NUM*
    { System.out.println("ID seen " + getText()); }
    ;

ID_SQLFUNC
    :   'h$' ALPHA_UPPER ALPHA_UPPER_NUM*
    { System.out.println("SQL FUNC seen " + getText()); }
    ;

WS0  :  [ \t]+ -> skip  ;

// all the following token are scanned only when iso mode is active
mode ISO;
ISO_END
    : '@>' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE)
    ;

WS0  :  [ \t]+ -> skip  ;
NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n' ;


ADD : '+' ;
SUB : '-' ;
LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;
P : 'P' ;
Y : 'Y' ;
M : 'M' ;
W : 'W' ;
D : 'D' ;

DATETIME_NAME
    :   TODAY
    |   NOW
    ;

fragment TODAY:   'today' | 'TODAY'    ;
fragment NOW :   'now' | 'NOW' ;


///////////////////////////////////////////

NUMBER_INT
    :   '-'? INT                    // -3, 45
    ;

fragment DIGIT :     [0-9] ;

fragment INT :       '0' | [1-9] DIGIT* ;

//////////////////////////////////////////////

fragment ALPHA :    [a-zA-Z] ;

fragment ALPH_NUM : [a-zA-Z_0-9] ;

fragment ALPHA_UPPER :    [A-Z] ;

fragment ALPHA_UPPER_NUM : [A-Z_0-9] ;
```

Such grammar can parse expressions like

```
Pluton Planet <% now + P10Y
%>
```

I changed a bit the parser rule `iso` to demonstrate ID and period mixing.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible what you wanna do. `ID` matches the same input as `iso8601_interval`. In such cases ANTLR4 picks the longest match, which is `ID` as it can match an unlimited number of characters.

The only way you could possible make it work in the grammar is to exclude `P` as a possible `ID` introducer, which then can exclusively be used for the duration.

Another option is a post processing step. Parse durations like any other identifier and in your semantic phase check all those ids that look like a duration. This is probably the best solution.